# AWS S3 query list one Partition file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

How to list all the files across domains in a S3 bucket is there any query in CLI or shell script to recursively return the dataset technical names under each origin in a bucket.

For example:

```
My bucket/domains/files
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Can you provide an example of what you are wanting? For example, can you show us an example directory structure with files and then show us what you would like to obtain from that?

Comment: In a S3 bucket  I have multiple origins inside each origin there is  data set technical name of files . I want to recursive list all the data set technical name under each origin in a bucket .   For example S3 bucket/ origin name/ data set technical name

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand -- what do you mean by "origins"? This is not a normal term applied to Amazon S3 buckets. Are your referring to subdirectories? What is a "data set technical name"? Are you referring to the filename of the object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), which will return a list of objects. If there are more than 1000 objects, you can use a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2) to easily loop through each object.

The API call will return a `Key` for each object, which consists of the **Full Path of the object** (eg `folder1/object.txt`).

Amazon S3 does not use 'folders' or 'subdirectories', so the listing will contain *all objects*. This is convenient because the complete listing can be easily obtained *without* needing to recurse through each subdirectory.

If you *do* need to recurse through the directories, you can use `list_objects_v2(Delimiter='/',Prefix='folder1/')` and it will only return a list of objects with that Prefix, which is effectively the same as a directory. It will also return a list of `CommonPrefixes` that are effectively the names of directories under that Prefix. However, recursing through the bucket this way will take many API calls and will be considerably slower.